# ASP.NET MVC - How to build custom viewmodels in C# to pass a data set to a strongly typed View?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to ASP.NET, C# and the MVC framework but have managed to build a site that works pretty well.

Now I am trying to create a reporting section for the site to display a table of information on all users and just can't get my head around creating custom model classes for the joined table data. I have seen lots of examples with one record but none with a full data set.

I am using the Entity framework and pulling my data out with:

```
var usersInfo = from c in _dataModel.UserProfile select new { c.Forname, c.Surname, c.aspnet_Users.UserName, c.Countries.CountryName, c.Specialities.SpecialityName};
```

The data returns fine, but it is of the type: `'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType6`5[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]'`

How would I get this into a type that I can pass back to a strongly typed View?

Thanks,

Giles

Comment: Your key word is strongly typed view.  If you didnt care for the strongly typed, use dynamic and the example you posted should work fine.

Comment: ...or, if you value your sanity, make the effort to remain strongly typed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a named class to hold the data that is currently encapsulated in the anonymous data you have selected:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Forename{get;set;}
    public string Surname{get;set;}
    //etc
}

var usersInfo = from c in _dataModel.UserProfile select new MyClass{ Forename=c.Forname, Surname=c.Surname, ...};
```

Now you've got a concrete type that you can throw around your app with ease. If you run into this a lot, refactoring tools such as Resharper can convert from anonymous to named types in a couple of clicks.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting errors in VS on the select that "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" and on my "{" because MyClass doesn't implement IEnumerable. Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's not possible to tell you with such little info. Your ViewPage is of which type? Assuming usersInfo will be the model, it should be IEnumerable<MyClass>. If problems persist then you'll have to state them more clearly.

Comment: They are build errors on the Controller rather than runtime View errors. Error 1 - Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type. Error 2 - Cannot initialize type 'HAE.Models.MyClass' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. I'm not even trying to push it to the View yet.

Comment: I've updated my code. Should eliminate the 2nd error. Any closer?

Comment: I think I just had the "ahhhaaaaa" moment I was looking for! Both errors gone and a working View. Thanks very much, Giles.